# Mongodb db query for inserting into whole scope value into array

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using `angularjs` and `mongodb` and I have schema like the object I paste here.
Now I need to store the whole scope value into an array.
Help how to do this and I need insert query for that.

**schema**

```
var Schema = new Schema({
    UnitId: String,
    UnitName: String ,

   Details:[{

   }],

    {strict: false});
```

**insert Query**

```
Details:[{         
            // here i want store my req.body scope value
       }],
```

Comment: basically you create a model and then you craete a new instance of that model. To save you use save() method. This is documented in detail in here : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: Save method okay how to save data inside the array

Comment: If you are inserting, you can directly add it inside the new as a argument an your new doc structure.. if you want to update you can use $set